# d3 localStorage.getItem() compare arrays .filter()

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, local-storage

I am trying to get values back from localStorage; multiple click counters in div elements. 
They were stored on click under key = this.id in localStorage; the values are the innerText of the divs.

Now: 1. I filter the selection looking for a match for element-ids in arraylocal
2. if match, set the html.

```
   d3.selectAll(".numberCircle").filter((d) -> this.id in arraylocal).html(localStorage.getItem(((d) -> this.id))
```

3. I would like to get values ( innerText from elements ) back out of localStorage using 'this.id'.
4. How can I set localStorage.getItem(x????x) to read the proper key/value pair ( where key = this.id ) ?

Thus: for each array filter match, I also need the localStorage **value** that is related to that match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

```
updateLabels = function() {

var arraylocal, key;
```

key in localStorage reflects a string in this solution, as I set a string value for setItem, e.g.:  setItem(string,string)

arraylocal is an array containing these strings

```
arraylocal = [];
for (key in localStorage) {
  arraylocal.push(key);
  console.log(arraylocal);
}
```

each bubble-label-name has a string value textValue(d).

The filter changes the style of the nodes when the string value textValue(d) matches a string 'key' in the array

```
d3.selectAll(".bubble-label-name").filter(function(d) {
  var ref;
  return ref = textValue(d), indexOf.call(arraylocal, ref) >= 0;
}).style("border", "2px solid red");

};
```